# Control/limit file versions for lage files in Nextcloud

Tags: synchronization

For security reasons, I'm packing extra sensitive information in Veracrypt containers before uploading them to my Nextcloud. I see my Nextcloud growing, since a small change inside the container result in a complete revision of the entire container:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 6.0G Mar  5 23:00 Privat.veracrypt.v1520196556
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 6.0G Mar  8 18:17 Privat.veracrypt.v1520365652
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 6.0G Mar 12 08:48 Privat.veracrypt.v1520457248
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 6.0G Mar 14 21:16 Privat.veracrypt.v1520891544
```

I've more of those revisions, which would result in a waste of space and slow down my backup process. Especially on a larger Veracrypt container, which is about 10GB big. Having a few versions would easily eat 100GB storage.

#### Is it possible to limit the amout of revisions for those files?

I don't want to disable file versioning at all cause it's usefull. Especially on single files like documents. But for Veracrypt containers it would be enough to keep the latest 5 versions or so. To reduce the container size, I already splitted my originally large container into 3 smaller ones. That's why more splitting doesn't really make sense and I'm looking for a way to limit those file versioning.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really for the problem itself. My current workaround is using [Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/de/). This open source tool encrypts every single file. So when I change the 100KB file called X, only this file got synced, instead of several GBs of some VC container.